# How to write the query using indexing in firebase?

Tags: indexing, firebase, angularjs-orderby

```
packages:{
           pack-a : "true",
           pack-b : "true",
           pack-c : "false",
           pack-d : "true",
           pack-e : "true",
}
```

I want to if there exists a package whose state is true using indexing in firebase.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good time to read the [Firebase documentation on queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries):

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://yours.firebaseio.com/packages');
var query = ref.orderByValue().equalTo('true');

query.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log('Are there packages? '+snapshot.hasChildren());
});
```